# How to create a Lookup<string, delegate> collection

Tags: .net, collections, delegates

I need to be able to filter a set of delegates in a collection based on a key. Each key will have one or more delegates associated with it. It looks like a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` could help out here, but I'm not sure if it's possible to create one where `TKey` is not derived from an attribute of `TElement` (in my case, `TElement` will be a delegate type and will not know anything about the identifier).

**Update**

For example, if I used a `Dictionary`, I might index and filter my list of delegates as in the example below:

```
private delegate MyMethod MethodName(string key);

IDictionary<string, MyMethod> methodList = new Dictionary<string, MyMethod>();
methodList.Add("Key1", Method1);
methodList.Add("Key1", Method2);
methodList.Add("Key2", Method3);
methodList.Add("Key3", Method4);
methodList.Add("Key3", Method5);

var someMethods = methodlist["Key3"];
```

However, this would fail because a `Dictionary` requires a unique key, and in my scenario, there are multiple entries per key. A `Lookup` supports multiple entries per key, but it is not possible to instantiate it using an `Add` method. I am looking for a way of instantiating a Lookup so that list of delegates are indexed with an arbitrary key.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this, please?

Comment: Hard to understand what you're asking about. Can you make it more clear? Perhaps with some code sample?

Comment: Added some sample code and more discussion above.

Comment: You can use `Dictionary<string, List<MyMethod>>` instead

Comment: What was the markdown for?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, thanks but I'm looking for a solution based on Lookup as I want to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by wrapping the delegate in a class that also incorporates the key:

```
private delegate MyMethod DoStuff();

private class MethodWrapper
{
    public MethodWrapper(string key, MyMethod method)
    {
        Key = key;
        Method = method;
    }
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public MyMethod Method { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can produce a lookup like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<GetChart> GetMethodList(string key)
{
    IEnumerable<MethodWrapper> methods = new List<MethodWrapper>()
    {
        new MethodWrapper("Key1", Method1),
        new MethodWrapper("Key2", Method2),
        new MethodWrapper("Key2", Method3)
    };
    ILookup<string, GetChart> lookup = methods.ToLookup(m => m.Key, m => m.Method);

    return lookup[key];
}
```